# Creating Detailed Report Using Microsoft RDLC Reporting

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have an **Order** object that has many **Job** objects included in it.

What I want to do is to create a report that has many Order objects displayed on it and then each of those order objects will have many Job objects underneath them.
I can't seem to link the two together, how do I go about doing this?

Using Microsoft RDLC reports - NOT Crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding RDLC difficult to impossible to build the report you need, then it is probably not a good fit for you. RDLC can do some types of reports easily, but if you get outside of its approach, it becomes very difficult.

There are a lot of other reporting systems out there. And some have a very different approach from Microsoft. Take a look and compare. (I'm not recomending because I'm the CTO of a reporting software company so I'm biased.)

Comment: I'm just a beginner with reporting systems. Hopefully I'll start understanding RDLC soon else we may look towards other options.